# Disable JPA with Jadira to convert time to UTC

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jodatime

I am using JPA 2 with hibernate 4 and MySQL server with MySQLConnector 5.1.26 and everything works fine except that when I save a date in my DB, somehow it saves the time in UTC.

Here is my model class:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private long id;
  @Column
  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
  private LocalDateTime startTime;
  @Column
  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
  private LocalDateTime endTime;
  @Column
  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
  private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

And here is my code that saves to database:

```
@Override
  public void save(MyModel model) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(model);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
  }
```

The save works fine and it saves to my database but with a different time. I leave in UTC+3 and it looks like it is converting it to UTC.
When I get the value back, it gets it back to the good value.

I am using LocalDateTime because I do not care about the time zone in the first place, so why does it make me a conversion?

**Methods I have tried to disable this automatic conversion**:

I tried(as peer Jadira documentation) :

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime",
    parameters = { @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "UTC"),
         @Parameter(name = "javaZone", value = "jvm")})
```

No luck, I wrote instead of UTC I wrote jvm.
I also tried to wrote this directly in the persistence.xml... Still no luck.
I tried to set my default JVM timezone to utc, no luck...

There has to be a way to disable this auto transform to UTC but I don't know exactly how to do it...

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: JPA 4.2.6 ? Maybe what you meant is Hibernate 4.2.6

Comment: Yes, you are right... it is JPA 2